# Do I need to factory reset to root galaxy note 4 SM-N910V?

Tags: root-access, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have the Samsung Galaxy note 4 for Verizon. I believe it is the developer edition because the model # is SM-N910V. I am trying to either install CFs auto root or install TWRP recovery and root from there. So far both fail in Odin. here's the log for Odin for CF auto root,

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> CF-Auto-Root-trltevzw-trltevzw-smn910v.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin v.3 engine (ID:3)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/003> recovery.img
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> cache.img.ext4
<ID:0/003> FAIL! (Auth)
<ID:0/003> 
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

I did a samsung update the other day and went from NI1 to NJ5, i guess that is the update version. Does updating remove the unlocked bootloader? Do I need to factory reset to be able to install CF auto root and TWRP?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the base model number for both the "developer edition" and the regular version are the same. Assuming you got it new, you would know if you had the developer edition, because you have to buy it full retail price from Samsung (Verizon won't sell it to you). Where did you purchase your device?

Comment: I purchased from Verizon. I was able to click on build number seven times under about phone and I was able to unlock the developer menu so are you sure about that?

Comment: If you got it from Verizon it's not the developer edition. You have a locked bootloader. There is currently [no known way to root your device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4-verizon/help/attempting-to-root-verizon-note-4-sm-t2962060). The presence of the development menu is not actually relevant for your purposes - you can use ADB for debugging and such without having a "developer edition" device with an unlockable bootloader. Supporting ADB is a requirement of Google's Android Compatibility Test Suite. Compliance with that is needed in order to ship the device with Google apps.

Comment: That link is only for the retail version. The model SM-N910V is supposed to be indicative of the developer model.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that the base model number for both *is the same*. The one sold by Verizon is the [SM-N910VZKEVZW](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-N910VZKEVZW). The developer edition is the [SM-N910VMKEVZW](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SM-N910VMKEVZW). Notice that **both** have a base model number of SM-N910V. The difference is that the dev edition has the "MKEVZW" part number and the Verizon-sold version is "ZKEVZW". Verizon **does not sell** the developer edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung devices usually have *no* locked bootloader so you won't remove that. Official updates *do* however remove any trace of a working root.
Your device is nowhere near a developer device but more a custom device served with a custom firmware of Verizon noticeable on the **V** in your model no.

Because of that custom Verizon model it is possible that the bootlader may be locked as you can see in the log where it says `<ID:0/003> FAIL! (Auth)`.
This means you are not authenticated to flash anything on your device which leads me to the assumption that your bootloader is Verizon-specific and therefore locked.

Comment: Verizon does indeed lock the bootloader on this device. I'm pretty sure they lock them on *all* their devices these days, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

i got same problem on Galaxy s7 edge, and now this is solved :
Developer Option - on - OEM unlock - On => run odin again. Done.